# NodeJS dynamically load angular modules after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, security

first of all I'm sorry, but I don't have a lot of exp in npm so please forgive me ^^

I have an http-server that uses angular. Right now I load all the modules ever needed right on the index.html like:

```html
<!-- internal js files -->
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app.config.js"></script>

<script src="do/something.module.js"></script>
<script src="do/something.component.js"></script>
<script src="do/another_thing.module.js"></script>
<script src="do/another_thing.component.js"></script>
```

So when the website loads, it also loads all the modules without verifying that I am 'allowed to see them'. This in turn makes it (imho) a big security risk, since an attacker can see what the website does and how it calls a private API in the modules...

As said I'm really not thaat experienced in this area.. so I was just wondering: what are common practices? How would / did you solve this issue?

Comment: Angularjs has a lazy load module, but seems that you have not using bundler...is that true?

Comment: ahh yes, thanks for the hint.. however, this just makes it harder to read, but doesn't quite solve the problem, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, what doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: I mean even if I bundle everything, all my modules still get loaded in right from the start, no? It doesn't change the behaviour of my app..

Comment: Correct, but with webpack as bundler it is much easier to code split a chunk of the code, and load it on route level, I can answer with my approach

Answer (score 2):

Lazy loading an AngularJs (v1.x) module is supported by [`$injector.loadNewModules`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#loadNewModules) (^v1.6.x).

**This example assumes `angularjs v1.6.x` & `@uirouter/angularjs v1.x.x`**

In order to prevent from an Angular module from being inside the app bundle, it **should not** be part of the app dependency tree, this means that the angular module `admin` won't be imported and used as part of the `app` angular module.

```js
// router config

$stateProvider
  .state('admin', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/admin',
    onEnter: /*@ngInject*/ (userService, $stateParams) => {
      return userService.getUserFromToken($stateParams.propertyId);
    },
    lazyLoad: $transition$ => {
             // this dynamic import tells webpack to split the admin-panel module (and it dependencies) from the app bundle
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "admin" */ '../admin-panel/admin-panel.module').then(
        module => $transition$.injector().loadNewModules([module.AdminPanelModule],
      );
    },
  })
  .state('admin.main', { // inherits from admin abstract state
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '@': {
        component: 'dashboard',
      },
    },
  });
```

with this state config, whenever your app will navigate to any of the `admin` pages (which inherits  from the abstract `admin` state) the `onEnter` will check if the user has permission for the page & then `lazyLoad` will be called (at the first time only) in-order to load the `admin.panel.module` to the app module.